# High pitched revving/sensitive gas pedal?

Tags: engine, manual-transmission

I live in the UK and went to go and test drive a 1.0L Peugeot 108. The car was in good condition and it's from a main dealer at a fair price which is why I am attracted to it. It was obviously sitting around on their forecourt for ages so the battery had died so I walked away and said if you put a new battery in right now I can come back for another test drive. I've also used the issues I found to negotiate a free major service when it's due in the summer.

My question is this though: I noticed when I first started the car that when I was setting my revs with my clutch down (in neutral), I would barely apply any pressure to the gas pedal and the car would rev quite loudly/high pitched. Now it wouldn't sound bad or broken, it would just rev a lot. I know it's a 1L so this might influence it, it just seemed that when I was revving even just a little bit in neutral it was a lot! When I engaged the gear and moved through the gears the engine sounded fine and it was all okay. When I'm going to go for another drive though I'll see again, just wondering if this is anything abnormal from my description?

Comment: What type of car are you used to driving that you are comparing it to?

Comment: Is it petrol or diesel?

Comment: It's a petrol. I've driven the 1.2L or more high powered versions of the same car a little bit and they didn't rev so much in neutral. The car im most used to driving is a 2.0L diesel so quite different

Comment: Without experiencing it myself, it would be very difficult to say if it is faulty of just revs very easily.  A small petrol engine should rev up quickly because it will have little moving mass.  A video you pressing the pedal may help someone compare it with their identical car.